# write output on a text file in Fortran code

Tags: fortran, output

I have a matrix A(3,4) in Fortran , I want to write it on a text file like this:

```
 A(1,1) A(2,1) A(3,1)
 A(1,2) A(2,2) A(3,2)
 A(1,3) A(2,3) A(3,3)
 A(1,4) A(2,4) A(3,4)
```

I use below code. It has two problems at first it is overwritten for each i and it is written in rows. I would be gratful to guide me to solve it. Thanks

```
      do i=1,4
      open (unit=10,file="out.txt",action="write")
      write (10,*)  A(1,i) , A(2,i) , A(3,i) 
      close (10)
```

Comment: This is just a small part of a matrix. I just write this one for example . My real matrix is A(180,200,430) . and I need just write some elements.

Comment: Why are you opening the file each time you go around the loop? Otherwise it's impossible to tell anything from this fragment - please show a complete code that has the problems you are encountering, and tell us exactly what the error messages are - it may all seem very obvious to you but this is the first time we are seeing this!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Ian, your file is overwritten for each i because your open statement is inside the loop. Fortran is reopening the file fresh for each i. Move the open statement to before the loop so it is only opened once.

Of course it is written in rows because the first index in a 2-D array is the row index. You can switch the indices if you wish. On the other hand, according to your first box, it appears as though you want the rows across the columns.

You say you need to write just some elements. As long as they are in a contiguous block, you will want to use an `implied do loop` in the write statement. It is much more concise and you can write large blocks without typing out a lot of variables specifically. It would look like this:

```
open (unit=10,file="out.txt",action="write")
do i=1,4
   write (10,*)  (A(j,i), j=1,3)
end do
close (10)
```

Again, this reverses rows and columns, if you want traditional representation, switch the i and j.

Comment: Why would we want the implied-do `(A(j,i) j=1,3)` instead of `A(1:3,i)`?